# Easy number formatting for axis of plots?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

Is there a trivial or extremely easy way to get this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One quick way could be

```
Plot[21000 x, {x, 42, 49}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[900000, 10^6, 50000]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it losses the minor ticks for some reason and I do not know now why. If I find, will update.

**Update**

Thanks to J.M.'s suggestion in the comment below. It is possible to create the ticks directly. Hence using his suggestion you could do

```
ClearAll[x];
divs = FindDivisions[21000 {42, 49}, {5, 5}];
yTicks = Flatten[Riffle[Transpose[{{divs[[1]], divs[[1]]}}, {2, 3, 1}], 
                 Map[Function[t, {t, "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}],
                     divs[[2]], {2}]], 1];
Plot[21000 x, {x, 42, 49}, Ticks -> {Automatic, yTicks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

J.M.'s method has the advantage that minor ticks are not lost which is better.

Comment: Here's something you can put in for the vertical ticks: `Flatten[Riffle[Transpose[{{#1, #1}}, {2, 3, 1}], Map[Function[t, {t, "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}], #2, {2}]], 1] & @@ FindDivisions[{882000, 1029000}, {5, 5}]`.

Comment: @J.M. that is very nice. I was trying this, but could not make it work: `p1 = Plot[21000 x, {x, 42, 49}]
oldTicks = AbsoluteOptions[pl, Ticks][[1, 2, 2]]` This gives the original ticks. But could find how to replace the labels. I was trying to use `AccountingForm`, then do `Show[p1, Ticks -> {Automatic, newTicks}]` where `newTicks` is the old ones, but changed the labels. This did not work. Your method seems to make everything from scratch. Please feel free to post this as answer.

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions[]` has been broken for a while, unfortunately. Also, I'd prefer you just edit your answer (I have upvoted already) to include that minor fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Wow, that escalated quickly! The Range[900000, 10^6, 50000] solution does not have generality. I was hoping to see something like AxisNumberForm -> Decimal. I guess that this is one point in favor of Excel, which is almost unbelievable.

Comment: @bowzee can you elaborate? How does this solution not “generalize”?